# getElementsByTagName exclude script tag

Tags: javascript, html

As the title suggests I want to exclude the script tag.

Cause while using regex (at least I think that's the right name :P)

I get to a point where something

```
var wdc = /something/g;
```

is included inside the

```
var foundwdc = words.match(wdc).length;
```

So when I alert foundwdc it gives 3 "somethings" instead of the desired two inside the body

```
var words = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

Hope this is clear enough :D and hope the title is right :P

Comment: I would recommend you move your Javascript to an external file that is loaded upon page load instead of having Javascript code inline in your HTML, that would solve your problem.

Comment: Gonna try that but I'm supposed to have the script inside the HTML but ok... still gonna try though :D Hope it helps

Comment: I don't get it. He still has to include the script tag in the document. How does it solve it?

Comment: For this to be answered you really need to show your HTML in order for us to reproduce your problem. Please read the "[MCVE]" guidelines.

Comment: My thought was that "something" was in the Javascript and not in the actual script tag, if that is the case then that wouldn't solve the problem. I just common sense to have your Javascript in separate files though.

Comment: Oh hello David I would do that but I wasn't sure if that would actually change anything :D :P , Gonna check Pranav's answer though

Comment: LOL no Sam xD something is <script>    var wdc = /something/g;    </script>   inside of it

Comment: @ToomanyQuestiondude Then using something like <script src="something.js"></script>, solves your problem.

Comment: @Sam Pettersson Well i tried that as u suggested in the beginning and didn't help cause I couldn't see the button :L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to remove the script tag from string

```js
var words = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');

console.log(words);
```

```html
hi hello
<script>
</script>
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/mJ4jK4/1).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: That's it ... Wow I'm so stupid... I tried it with trim() but didn't work and got stuck :P ... Thx a lot!!!